# displaying one to many relationships with crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have two tables in my database :

```
Order(OrderID, Date, ClientID)
OrderItem(OrderID, ProductID, Quantity)
```

1 Order can have multiple OrderItem(s). It's a one-to-many relationship.

I want to display these records in a master-detail fashion, as such :

```
        Order 1 :
            -OrderItem2
            -OrderItem4

        Order 2:
             -OrderItem10
```

In my asp.net app, I have created a single DataSet that contains two DataTables (Order and OrderItem). the two datatables have a relationship based on the OrderID.

my questions are :

```
  - Is this the right way to go in this situation ?
  - Is there a more natural way to do this in Crystal Reports ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way is to just group your report by Order (specifically, the OrderID). You can then place the OrderItem data in the Details Section of the report and Order data in the Group Header section of the report and it will display as you've described.

Comment: do you mean I should send into the report a single datatable and then do the grouping inside the report ?

Comment: Yes, do the grouping inside the report. You should be fine with the dataset as it is.